# "more elements supplied than there are to replace" when trying to generate date in columns R

Tags: r

Hello i have run into a problem when trying to itreate a functionm and organizing them into colmuns. Basically i want to create a dataset of fake stocks:

[][v1]  [v2]  [v3]  [v4]  [v5]

[1]

[2]

[3]

[4]

[5]

However when i it i get the error: *"Error in stock_gen[[i]] <- as.matrix(rtsplot.fake.stock.data(n, y0 = 10,  :
more elements supplied than there are to replace"*
here is my code:

```
library("rtsplot")
i = 5
n = 5
stock_gen <- matrix(ncol = n, nrow = i)

for(i in stock_gen){
stock_gen[[i]] <- 
as.matrix(rtsplot.fake.stock.data(
  n,
  y0 = 10,
  stdev = 0.1,
  ohlc = FALSE,
  method = c("normal", "adhoc"),
  period = c("day", "minute"),
  remove.non.trading = FALSE
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't have to be a matrix (and even then you can easily convert back from dataframe to matrix), here's one possible blueprint:

```
library(rtsplot)

i = 5 ## row count
n = 5 ## column count

stock_gen <- 
    as.data.frame(
        structure(lapply(1:n, function(x){
            rtsplot.fake.stock.data(n = i,
                                    y0 = 10 ##, other arguments ...
                                    )
        }
        ),
        names = paste0('series_',LETTERS[1:5]))
    )
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly. You are a god send.

Comment: Feeling flattered :-) But I remember quite well those periods of frustration, trying to make sense of the existence of all those similar-but-different structures like lists, vectors, matrices, dataframes ... it was not before I understood that dataframes are "nothing but" lists of equal-length columns which in turn are vectors (well, usually) when things began to click.